# To prove an open set in $(V,\lVert\cdot\rVert_2)$ is also open in $(V,\lVert\cdot \rVert_\infty)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space of all continuous complex-valued functions on [a,b]. $X_1=(V,\lVert\cdot\rVert_2)$ and $X_2=(V,\lVert\cdot \rVert_\infty)$, where $\lVert x(t)\rVert_2=[\int_a^b|x(t)|^2\,\textrm{d}t]^{1/2}$ and $\lVert x(t)\rVert_\infty=\max\lvert x(t)\rvert $. Then show that any open set in $X_1$ is also open in $X_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\Vert f\Vert_2 \leq \sqrt{b-a}\Vert f \Vert_{\infty}$.

One gets this inequality in the following way:

$$ \Vert f\Vert_2 = \left( \int_a^b \vert f(x)\vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2}
\leq \left( \int_a^b \vert \  \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} \ \vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2} = \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} \cdot \left( \int_a^b 1 dx \right)^{1/2} = \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} \sqrt{b-a}.$$

What does this tell you about open balls in $X_1$ and $X_2$?

The inequality tells you that

$$ \{  x\in V: \Vert x \Vert_{\infty} < c \} \subseteq  \{ x\in V: \Vert x \Vert_2 <c \sqrt{b-a}  \}.$$

Comment: @Severin Kindly tell me some hint to prove this inequality.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  Yes, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Let A be an open set in $X_1$. Then for all $f\in A$ there is $r >0$ $B_r(f) \subset A$
Let $ g \in B_r(f)$, then $||(f-g)(t)||_2=[\int_a^b|(f-g)(t)|^2dt]^{1/2} <r$

Now, for all $x \in [a,b]$ we have $|(f-g)(x)|  \leq max{|(f-g)(x)|}$

Thus $\sqrt{\int_a^b|(f-g)(t)|^2dt}$ $\leq \sqrt{\int_a^b|max{(f-g)(x)}|^2dt}$ $=\sqrt{b-a}*|max{(f-g)(x)}|$ = $\sqrt{b-a}*\Vert f-g \Vert_{\infty}$

Now in $X_2$ we will have that $B_s(f) \subset A$, $r = s*\sqrt{b-a}$
Thus, A is open in $X_2$